# Set JAVA_HOME in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java

I have to set JAVA_HOME on `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` or `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/`??

Comment: Please run `update-alternatives --config java` to determine what to set! Put that into your question

Comment: I `checked update-alternatives --config java` before ask  and  java is in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/`  but I'm not sure if I have to include the bin directory because some answers include it and some not